# Best option to update Facebook contact list in Android app

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm working on an application that retrieves the list of Facebook contacts to later perform different actions with it (for example, open a chat).

I have retrieved the list, but I have doubts about which is the best strategy to preserve and applying it to the changes that occur (eg chat be available for a new contact).

What is the best approach? As a first option I created a java class and serialized entire contact list (with their profile picture). After I have saved on the SD card and leave it available for later retrieval when needed. But I'm thinking maybe it is better to create a service in Android that instantiates a class that store a HashMap of contacts and leave it in memory for watching it constantly updating.

What do you think about this?

thanks